# Make all cells editable in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables 1.10.12 and I am having a simple table being drawn with:

```
projectRevenue = $('#projectRevenue').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    scrollX: true,
    stateSave: true,
    ajax: {
            url: "{!! route('listOfProjectsRevenueAjax',$project->id) !!}",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON"
        },
    columns: [
        { name: 'id', data: 'id' , searchable: false , visible: false },
        { name: 'year', data: 'year' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'product_code', data: 'product_code' , searchable: true , visible: true  },
        { name: 'jan', data: 'jan' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'feb', data: 'feb' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'mar', data: 'mar' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'apr', data: 'apr' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'may', data: 'may' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'jun', data: 'jun' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'jul', data: 'jul' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'aug', data: 'aug' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'sep', data: 'sep' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'oct', data: 'oct' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'nov', data: 'nov' , searchable: true , visible: true },
        { name: 'dec', data: 'dec' , searchable: true , visible: true },
```

I would like to be able to edit the cells so that it will get updated in the database. For this I would need to have each  with contenteditable set to true and to have a class for example update => for this, I add className: "update", but I don't know how to make it content editable.

Comment: You don't need to add extra attributes to cells to make them editable. You just need to decide which way your cell data input fields will be arranged - it's either you want your row cells to turn into `<input>`/`<select>` upon clicking them (to edit those in place), or you may throw bootstrap modal with all the selected row(s) data input fields and submit edits button. Upon that you may just do ajax-call to your backend with updated data and do `.ajax.reload()` on DataTable to refresh up-to-date table contents.

Comment: If you shed some more light onto how exactly you want your table to get editable, maybe I may suggest some exact code snippets that might come in handy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make all cells in a DataTable editable this way :

```
const createdCell = function(cell) {
  let original

  cell.setAttribute('contenteditable', true)
  cell.setAttribute('spellcheck', false)

  cell.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    original = e.target.textContent
  })

  cell.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    if (original !== e.target.textContent) {
      const row = table.row(e.target.parentElement)
      row.invalidate()
      console.log('Row changed: ', row.data())
    }
  })
}

table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs: [{ 
    targets: '_all',
    createdCell: createdCell
  }]
})
```

As you can see in this demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w9hrnf63**

They key part is `row.invalidate()`. This updates the row data internally if and only if you are working with a DOM table or other static resource. If you are using `serverSide` processing `invalidate()` will just reset the cell content back to original. So execute your update request to the server instead of `invalidate()` above :

```
cell.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  if (original !== e.target.textContent) {
    const row = table.row(e.target.parentElement)
    $.ajax({
      url: '/updateScript/',
      data: row.data()
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @davidkonrad's code and explanation also worked fine for me. Only after the data was entered, the console.log of row.data() showed no update. However, adding

```
row.data()[cell.cellIndex] = e.target.textContent;
```

which updates the chace in real time, worked like a charm.